# Vue js is changing url

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm passing a url to v-for element:

```html
<section v-for="section in sections" :key="section.i" :id="`${section.class}`" :style="`--img: url(${section.img})`" :class="`main__section main__section--${section.classMod}`">
      <div class="main__section__img"></div>
      <article class="main__section__text">
        <h1 class="main__section__text__title">{{ section.title }}</h1>
        <p class="main__section__text__content">{{ section.content }}</p>
      </article>
</section>
```

in  `:style="--img: url(${section.img})`"
and instead of getting:

`https://static.pexels.com/photos/206130/pexels-photo-206130.jpeg`

I get:

`https\:\/\/static\.pexels\.com\/photos\/206130\/pexels-photo-206130\.jpeg`

I'm using Vue Webpack template with svg loader
My webpack.base.conf.js:

```js
'use strict'
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('./utils')
const config = require('../config')
const vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

const createLintingRule = () => ({
  test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
  loader: 'eslint-loader',
  enforce: 'pre',
  include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
  options: {
    formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter'),
    emitWarning: !config.dev.showEslintErrorsInOverlay
  }
})

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src'),
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      ...(config.dev.useEslint ? [createLintingRule()] : []),
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test'), resolve('node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[a|c]ss$/,
        loader: 'style!css!sass'
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        loader: 'vue-svg-loader', // `vue-svg` for webpack 1.x
        options: {
          // optional [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo) options
          svgo: {
            plugins: [
              {removeDoctype: true},
              {removeComments: true}
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]'),
          publicPath: process.env === 'production' ? '../../' : './'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('media/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  node: {
    // prevent webpack from injecting useless setImmediate polyfill because Vue
    // source contains it (although only uses it if it's native).
    setImmediate: false,
    // prevent webpack from injecting mocks to Node native modules
    // that does not make sense for the client
    dgram: 'empty',
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    child_process: 'empty'
  }
}
```

How do I fix that?
I've tried using `.replace(/\\*/g, "")` but it doesn't work :(

Comment: *
I'm getting: "https\:\/\/static\.pexels\.com\/photos\/206130\/pexels-photo-206130\.jpeg"

Answer (score 1):

How about binding your style like this:

```
:style="{ background: 'url(' + section.img + ')' }"
```

Comment: It works :)
`
<div class="main__section__img" :style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + section.img + ')' }"></div>`